# How can I do thing like arrow in design of div?

Tags: css, html

How can I do thing like arrow in design of div?
[image: div]

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on exactly in that image. But my guess would be a background image property change in CSS.

Comment: This is the top of the div using as popup. I know I can do this thing by background image, but I expected there is better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a triangle as a pseudoelement using borders is one way to do it, but your mockup includes a box-shadow. If you don't want to sacrifice the box-shadow (because using the border technique, it will create a square shadow and look quite bad), there is a way.

Create *two* pseudoelements styled as absolutely positioned squares, and rotate them 45 degrees. Set just one of them to a lower stacking order than the default (`z-index: -1`) and apply the box shadow to that element.

[Check out the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stuajc/re7QH/1/)

HTML:
`<div class="container"></div>`

CSS:

```
.container:before,
.container:after {
    content: '';
    width: 2em; height: 2em;
    position: absolute; top: -1em; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -.5em;
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.container:before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I just agonized yesterday and could not make the shadow. It's the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a triangle, do something like this.. I will leave the positioning to you.

HTML

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.triangle {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 9px 15px 9px;
border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
```

For example purposes, the triangle is blue.. you are obviously going to want to make it white/transparent for what you are trying to achieve.

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DW33L/)</kbd>

For positioning, I would suggest using the `:after` / `:before` pseudo selector.

Comment: Ooo. I've never heard of the before and after pseudo selectors until today. after a bit of googling, they seem quite fun to play with. I'm getting some interesting ideas....

Answer (score 2):

```
<aside></aside>

aside {
   background: lightgray;
   height: 5em;
   position: relative;
   width: 10em;
}

aside::after {
   background: lightgray; 
   border-bottom: .8em solid lightgray;
   border-left: .4em solid transparent; 
   border-right: .4em solid transparent;
   content: "";
   left: 10%;
   position: absolute;
   top: -.6em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7UUqa/4/

Comment: Nice example.. you beat me again. +1

Comment: @JoshC So, Basically it's just a small bottom border on any "box" tag?